# How do I check for a segment in query string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the following error but for some reason its on a guid that is not available in the uril i thought i could just do a check if empty but of course the key does not exist

This is not a duplicate its asking how to check for the actual key it self to see if it exists. !!!

```
Line 23: 
Line 24:                 player _player = new player();
Line 25:                 Guid id = new         
Guid(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());
Line 26:                 if (id == Guid.Empty)
Line 27:                 {
```

This is the code in its entitirety

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            player _player = new player();
            Guid id = new Guid(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());
            if (id == Guid.Empty)
            {


            }
            else
            {
                _player = _dal.GetPlayerBYID(id);


                if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    if (_player.Name != null)
                        txtFullName.Text = _player.Name;
                    if (_player.address != null)
                        txtAddress.Text = _player.address;

                    dlGenders.SelectedValue = _player.gender;

                }


            }


            var dlGendersSource = _dal.GetGenders();
            dlGenders.DataSource = dlGendersSource;
            dlGenders.DataValueField = "LookupValue";
            dlGenders.DataTextField = "LookupDescription";
            dlGenders.DataBind();



            string message = "";
            if (Context.User.IsInRole("canEdit"))
            {
                //enable edit controls on page

                message += "This user can edit a record";
            }
            else if (Context.User.IsInRole("canDelete"))
            {
                //enable delete controls on page
                message += "This user can delete a record.";
            }
            else if (Context.User.IsInRole("canAdd"))
            {
                //enable delete controls on page
                message += "This user can add a record.";
            }
            RadNotification1.Position = NotificationPosition.BottomRight;
            RadNotification1.Text = message;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new EntityContextException("Page Load Failed in Edit Players  .", ex);
        }


    }
```

Screen Shot to show error It cause a team wont always have a player id attached at first so i need to be able to handle that until save changes is called.

[image]

Guys its this part that im having the issue so no downvotes !!!!

```
       Guid id = new Guid(Request.QueryString["id"]);
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Request.QueryString["id"] is already a string, if its null calling ToString() is a bad idea.

Comment: its a null error so it is but wont i still get the null

Comment: `string id = Request.QueryString["id"]; if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) { ... use it ...}`

Comment: @Kritner no cause in my case i cant check for the value as the key is not present !

Comment: What is the problem? If its not present it will be `null`

Comment: @AlexK. see the stack trace urself i dont no where on earth its getting g from

Comment: `g` is the Guid() constructor arguments internal name, you pass null as its value which is not valid hence the error.

Comment: @kymberly learn to code as well as use the `Debugger` these are tools that are right at your disposal. this is not a `Forum`

Answer (score 3):

change this way

```
        Guid id = new Guid(Request.QueryString["id"] ?? "");
        if (id == Guid.Empty)
```

...

Comment: thank you for being postivive

Comment: That will throw; new Guid("") is no more valid than new Guid(null)

Comment: its still saying guid in System.FormatException: Unrecognized Guid format.

Comment: You must pass it a valid guid *string*, you don't have one if your id value is not present, what do you want to do?

Comment: that is what im trying to do but the key wont always be theri that is what im trying to cross as im trying to use the same screen for two tasks !

Comment: So if there is no id you want a new Guid? -> `string id = Request.QueryString["id"]; var guid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) ? new Guid() : new Guid(id);`